# Display specific array value on textview ANDROID

Tags: android, android-listview

I got a asynctask listview that displays name, email, phonenumber. I update the name of the selected item on a dialog box but it shows it as an array. How can make it show a specific value for example "Name"?

Default: Name: name1, email:email@email.com, mobile:000
When I open dialog box textview will show {email=email,name=name,id=c201,mobile=000}

**I want this to show just 'name' on the textview**

ListView lv = getListView();

```
// Listview on item click listener
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, final int position, long id) {

        // getting values from selected ListItem
        final String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
        String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.email)).getText().toString();
        String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mobile)).getText().toString();

        // Create custom dialog object
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        // Include dialog.xml file
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
        // Set dialog title
        dialog.setTitle("Custom Dialog");

        // set values for custom dialog components - text, image and button
        final TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.name_label);
        text.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        dialog.show();

        new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                String itemValue =  (lv.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
                text.setText(itemValue);
            }

            public void onFinish() {

            }
        }.start();
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your listview must have been bound a adapter,and your text on textview comes from an array,so you should get the every string from your array data,not from listview directly.

Replace  :

```
String itemValue =  (lv.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
```

with:

```
String itemValue =  (YourArray[position].toString());//YourArray is your data array for showing text on textview
```

Answer (score 1):

To get data from Listview 
You can get data directly from your List of data (ArrayList, String[], JsonArray whatever you have used) using the position what you got from `onItemClick`

eg. Arraylist `listArrayObj.get(position)` 
JsonArray `listJsonarrayArrayObj.get(position)`
String[] than `yourStrArra[position]`

**Suggestion**

**DON'T**

```
final String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
                String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.email))
                        .getText().toString();
                String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mobile))
                        .getText().toString();
```

**DO**

fetch value of array directly from the Array which is passing in adapter